# Integrating $x\cdot{\cosh(x^2)}$

Tags: calculus

How do integrate $x\cdot{\cosh(x^2)}$?

Do i just use integration by parts?

I know that integration by parts is $\int{u\cdot{\mathrm{d}v}} = uv - \int{v\cdot{\mathrm{d}u}}$

Making $v=\frac{1}{2}x^2,\mathrm{d}v=x \ , \ u=\cosh(x^2), \mathrm{d}u=2x \sinh(x^2)$ I get $$ \int{x \cosh(x^2)}\mathrm{d}x=\frac{1}{2}x^2\cosh(x^2)-\int x^3\sinh(x^2)\mathrm{d}x$$
How do i go from here? it seems that another round of integration by parts will only complicate things.

Comment: After 4 months on this site you should know some basic LaTeX.

Comment: For $x\cosh(x^2)$, use substitution. The function $\cosh(x^2)$ of the title (but not of the question) does not have an elementary antiderivative.

Comment: Null you are right i should have looked at the thread about latex ages ago. I actually tried to learn latex before on another site because really hard for that site. In here it is much easier. I did the latex on one of my questions before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\int x\cosh(x^2)dx$$

substitute $x^2=u$
$$2x dx\Leftarrow\Rightarrow du$$
$$\int \frac{\cosh(u)}{2}du$$
$$\int x\cosh(x^2)dx=\frac{\sinh(u)}{2}+C=\frac{\sinh(x^2)}{2}+C$$
$$\int x\cosh(x^2)dx=\frac{\sinh(x^2)}{2}+C$$

Comment: +some C as integrating constant.

Comment: @Galc127 Yes, +C as integrating constant

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help =)